# Is java read only ByteBuffer a right object to have immutable byte array?

Tags: java, multithreading, immutability, bytebuffer, immutable-collections

I need to have immutable array of bytes that will be used in multithreaded environment. I came across `ByteBuffer` class, it's possible to make as read only with `.asReadOnlyBuffer` method.

However I'm wondering is that a right immutable bytes container, the following is concerning me:

1. If `ByteBuffer` was created with `ByteBuffer.wrap()` then the initial array may be changed, it will cause a change in `ByteBuffer` regardless the `.asReadOnlyBuffer`.
2. Is read operation from read only `ByteBuffer` safe with multithreading?

Any other concerns?

Comment: From the [documentation of Buffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html) (the superclass of ByteBuffer): “Buffers are not safe for use by multiple concurrent threads. If a buffer is to be used by more than one thread then access to the buffer should be controlled by appropriate synchronization.”  A read-only Buffer’s *data* may be immutable, but its position, limit, mark, etc., are not.

Comment: I see, missed this information. Thanks for the comment, it answers the question.

Comment: Do you need access to methods such as `getDouble()` or `getInt()`? AFAICT these methods are not thread safe. If you provide the index yourself there shouldn't be a problem. However you can always call `duplicate()` or `asReadOnlyBuffer()` again.

Comment: No, I don't need access to these methods. Anyway the `ByteBuffer` seems not the best object for my case.